# Message Popup Should Start at the end by default in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I have implemented a chat on click to conversation the scroll is start from bottom but first it showing on top then using ref scroll is coming to down.
I dont want to show it is scrolling down it just stat from end just like facebook, skype etc.

Currently I am doing using this

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
const refForScrollingToLastElement = useRef(null);

    const messages = [
  {message: 'message1'},
  {message: 'message2'},
  {message: 'message3'},
  {message: 'message4'},
  {message: 'message5'},
  {message: 'message6'},
  {message: 'message7'},
  {message: 'message8'},
  {message: 'message9'},
  {message: 'message10'},
  {message: 'message11'},
  {message: 'message12'},
  {message: 'message13'},
  {message: 'message14'},
  {message: 'message15'},
  {message: 'message16'},
  {message: 'message17'},
  {message: 'message18'},
];


    const scrollToEnd = () => {
    if (refForScrollingToLastElement.current) {
      refForScrollingToLastElement.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    }
  }


    retun(
    <>
    <div>
messages.map(item => <p>{item.message}</p>)
</div>
<div
      ref={refForScrollingToLastElement}
      style={{
        height: 1,
        width: 100,
      }}
    ></div>
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.scrollBy(x, y)` instead of using the element's scroll.
I updated the function to find the `div` height (including all the children), then used that height to scroll the window.

Notice that I placed the function in a `useEffect` so the render is updated. Here it is:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToEnd();
  }, []);

  function scrollToEnd() {
    if (refForScrollingToLastElement.current) {
      const divHeight = refForScrollingToLastElement.current.offsetHeight;
      window.scrollBy(0, divHeight);
    }
  }
```

Made a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-matan-lonoze?file=/src/App.js:163-409) so you can see the behavior.

Comment: Yes I have used in useEffect. I made the changes as you told but still scroll is sjowing that is is coming down. 

This is my behaviour now. https://gyazo.com/cac3862795f22ec08dc4448c6ebd7e39

I dont want to show scroll is coming down it should directly start from end without scroll.

Comment: Can you create a CodeSandbox and replicate your issue there? Without more code, is going to be difficult to figure out what's wrong.
Another possible solution, is to put a `loader` component on top, this component will be absolute and will hide once the scroll is done.